# Python if funtion not working as intended

Tags: python

I took Python last year in college and likeed it so much I decided to start using it or at least try.

I'm struck on the below code. Basically I want it to only print the service that was stopped or started, but it's printing the services all the time. Below is part of the code I have. I'm still very new to Python, so I know this must be something I'm doing wrong.

```
c = wmi.WMI()

  for s in c.Win32_Service():
    if s.State == 'Stopped':
            service_name = ['SolarWindsAdministration','SolarWindsAgent64','SolarWindsAlertingServiceV2'
                      ,'SWCollectorService','SolarWindsCortex','SWInfoServiceSvc','SWInfoServiceSvcV3','SWJobEngineSvc2',
                      'SWBrowserIntegration','SolarWindsRecommendations','SolarWindsSyslogService',
                      'SolarWinds TFTP Server',
                      'SolarWinds NetPerfMon',][enter image description here][1]
            s.StartService(service_name)
            print(service_name, s.State)
```

Comment: The formatting is so messy as to obscure what you might have tried to copy/paste here. Please [edit] the question to show your actual Python code with correct indentation. On the desktop version of this site, you can paste your code, then select it and type ctrl-K to have it properly formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the copy/pasted code, when defining service_name, `[enter image description here][1]` does not make sense. I assume it is a typo.
From what you said, here is an example of corrected code (for restarting services). You still have to adapt it if you want to stop services.

```
import wmi
services_to_monitor = ['SolarWindsAdministration','SolarWindsAgent64',
                       'SolarWindsAlertingServiceV2','SWCollectorService',
                       'SolarWindsCortex','SWInfoServiceSvc',
                       'SWInfoServiceSvcV3','SWJobEngineSvc2',
                       'SWBrowserIntegration','SolarWindsRecommendations',
                       'SolarWindsSyslogService','SolarWinds TFTP Server',
                       'SolarWinds NetPerfMon']
c = wmi.WMI()
for service in c.Win32_Service():
    if service.Name in services_to_monitor and service.State == 'Stopped':
        result, = service.StartService()        
        if result == 0:
            print("Service " +str(service.Name)+" started")
        else:
            print("Oops. Something went wrong starting "+str(service.Name))
```